# What does this htaccess code say?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have this piece of code :

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

i know what it does, and it does the job well! (if someone access the page with a non https url, the code represents them with the https url).
but my problem is that i don't understand the condition and i don't understand why does it do, what it does.
so i will be thankful if you help me understand the condition and the way this code works.

Comment: [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) may be helpful in general, but it's not an explanation of your sample of course.

Comment: well, i was working on the code above for like 2-3 hours and everything i was doing based on what i read on Apache site was exactly the opposite and didn't do what i needed to. then i asked someone for help and he porvided me this code which works perfectly but based on my knowledge i cannot figure out why it works at all!

Comment: just to be sure you haven't missed that step; then, I agree it's fine to ask such kind of Q here or elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if someone access the page with a non https url, the code represents them with the https url

Actually no, that's not what it does, exactly. The condition checks that the hostname (everything after the `http://` or `https://` and before the next following `/`). is **not** "domain.com", and if that's the case, it redirects every request to the **https** version of the "domain.com" host.

So if you go to `http://domain.com/`, you *won't* get redirected.

But if you go to `http://www.domain.com/`, you *will* get redirected to the *https* of the "domain.com" without the "www".

So the rule essentially enforces that the requested hostname is *always* "domain.com", and it just so happens to redirect to HTTPS.

If you want to force HTTPS, you can add an additional condition:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i only noticed today that my code was not doing exactly as i thought, but yours works like a charm :) thanks for your answer.